# Can I use WebWorkers in AWS Lambda (node 6.10)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, web-worker

I've got a very simple node module that I want in AWS lambda, and its importing 'Natural' for some text processing.

This line throws the error:
`var n = require('natural');`

The error is this:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "/var/task/node_modules/webworker-threads/build/Release/WebWorkerThreads.node: invalid ELF header",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "bindings (/var/task/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/webworker-threads/index.js:1:105)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)"
  ]
}
```

and it returns a

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Does AWS lambda not run webworkers?  I've tried compiling with nvm 6.10 exactly and rebuilt the zip file, but to no avail.  Is there something else I need to include in the zip to make sure the aws lambda env supports the webworker module?

EDIT: (Solved)
I wrote up a long tutorial and blog with code to dockerize the Native compilation process.

https://medium.com/@james_mtc/how-to-unsuck-aws-lambdas-native-compilation-for-nodejs-functions-with-docker-and-bash-5301a26a19b1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You need to build the native modules on an Amazon AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/) with static rather than shared/dynamic libraries. Changing a module from shared to static might be non trivial for some packages.

> Native modules are similarly installed and deployed, but you’ll need
>   to build them against the Amazon Linux libraries. You’ll need to
>   either ensure that the libraries and their transitive dependencies are
>   statically compiled or use rpath-style linking; we’ll do it the static
>   way in this post, and demonstrate use of rpath in a subsequent post.
>   (Note that many, but not all, libraries can be statically linked this
>   way.)